# На чем создаются 3d игры работающие в вебе?

Tags: веб-программирование, flash, разработка-игр

Доброго времени суток. Всегда думал, что все игры создаются во флэше или сильверлайте. А в чем создана например вот [такая](http://vkontakte.ru/app1908901_55932879?ref=5) игра? Насколько я понимаю, это 3d и аниматоры говорят, что это не флэш?..

Comment: это флеш, и это не 3D, а просто пререндеренные спрайты.

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ - Unity.
http://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 1):

WebGL, Silverlight, Flash (какая то сборка название не помню), другие плагины которые пользователю ПРИДЕТСЯ ставить (что не всегда возможно, что нежелательно, что раздражает и т.д.). ИМХО лучший выбор - webGL.

Comment: Еще как вариант - Java.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! Alternativa 3d - бесплатный движек (а так же плагины для редакторов и мануалы), как раз для этих целей. В условиях использования только размещение ссылки на сайт разработчиков.
http://alternativaplatform.com/ru/alternativa3d/

Answer (score 0):

также есть движок для флеш под названием Papervision3D. На мой взгляд он несколько лучше. Но если вы хотите поддержать отечественных производителей, то выбирайте альтернативу 3d.

Answer (score 0):

Можно на Silverlight, вот хороший движок: [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/)

А месяц назад анонсировали полную аппаратную поддержку 3D в Silverlight 5, и интеграцию с XNA Api, а это значит, что можно будет использовать все возможности DirectX9 и свои шейдеры. Так что Silverlight очень перспективная технология, и работает как в Win среде, так и на Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Альтернатива 3d и flash плеер 11 версии.Пример:танки онлайн,метро 2033.